# Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$ such that $\gcd(|H|,|N|)=1$. Prove $H \times N \cong H \cdot N$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$ such that $\gcd(|H|,|N|)=1$. Prove $H \times N \cong H \cdot N$.

$\gcd(|H|,|N|)=1 \implies H \cap N=\{e\} $.

$H,N$ are normal subgroups of $G \implies $$HN \leq G$.

$|HN|=\frac{|H|\cdot|N|}{|H \cap N|}=|H|\cdot|N|$

Denote $q: HN \to H \times N, hn\mapsto (h,n)$ and I'll show that $q$ is well-defined and injective.

Well-defined:

Let $h_1n_1,h_2n_2\in HN$ such that $h_1n_1=h_2n_2.$

I have to show $q(h_1n_1)=q(h_2n_2)=(h_1,n_1)=(h_2,n_2)$.

$h_1n_1=h_2n_2\implies h_2^{-1}h_1n_1=n_2\implies h_3n_1=n_2\implies h_3=n_2n_1^{-1}\implies h_3\in N$.

Since $h_3\in H \cap N\implies h_3=\{e\} \implies n_1=n_2,h_1=h_2.$

Hence $q$ is well-defined.

$q$ is injective:

By definition of $q$,$(h_1,n_1)=(h_2,n_2) \iff h_1=h_2$ and $n_1=n_2$ hence $q$ is injective.

Since $q$ is injective and $|HN|=|H|\cdot|N| \implies H\times N \cong H \cdot N$.

Is my solution correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't shown that $q$ is a homomorphism! Also it would be easier to write it in the other direction as $(h, n) \mapsto hn$, then there's no issue with being well-defined.

Comment: I think about my solution again , isn't is suffecient to define $q$ as $(h, n) \mapsto hn$,since $H\cap N=\{e\} $ using the first isomorphism theorem , $H\times N \cong Im(q)\leq HN$  and since $|HN|=|H||N| \implies HN\cong H\times N $ ?

Comment: You need to check $q(h_1h_2,n_1n_2)=q(h_1,n_1)q(h_2,n_2)$ (i.e., that $q$ is a group homomorphism), which is not a priori obvious. You can only use the isomorphism theorem for group homomorphisms!